# How to paste in a value in a column dependent on another column value

Tags: r

I am trying to run code that creates a new variable by pasting in the value of an existing column based on whether a condition is true, using this dataset

I would like to create a new variable new_var that is set equal to Var4 and pastes in the Var3 value, if the Var4 value is NA, so it would take these values (1.8, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)

```
    df <- data.frame(var3=c(3.1, 2.0, NA, NA, 5.0),
                     var4=c(1.8, NA, 3.0, 4.0, NA))


    df$any.4[df$var4 != "NA"] <- 1
```

the any.4 flag indicates if var4 is missing or not and if any.4 = NA, then it would paste in the Var3 value. thoughts?